# Image slider jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#forward_carousel").click( () => {
  //sets timeout back and starts
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = 0;
  var i;
  var x = $(".carousel_size");//class for the pictures in carousel
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  timeout =setInterval(carousel, 5000);
})
$("#backward_carousel").click( () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = 0;
  var i;
  var x = $(".carousel_size");//class for the pictures in carousel
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex--;
  if (slideIndex < x.length){slideIndex = 3}
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  timeout =setInterval(carousel, 5000);
})
```

the forward button is working, but the backward button is just working if the current picture is at index 1. If the index is not at 1 the backward button is not working at all.

Comment: what for is this? `if (slideIndex < x.length){slideIndex = 3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your condition for backward index is not correct.**

Change this line:

```
 if (slideIndex < x.length){slideIndex = 3}
```

To this:

```
 if (slideIndex < 0){slideIndex = x.length}
```